# PHP CSV parser for 15000 rows optimization

Tags: php, laravel, csv, parsing, csv-parser

I need to parse some CSV data and store it to the database. The input file is about 15000 rows. It is written in Laravel framewrok. The request to DB spend about 0.2s so it seems the problem is in CSV parser. Can somebody tell me how to optimize this code in PHP. The code looks like this:

```
protected function csv2array(string $csv)
{
    try {
        $return = [
            'headers' => [],
            'rows' => [],
        ];
        $rows = explode(PHP_EOL, $csv);

        $headers = str_getcsv(strtolower(array_shift($rows)));  // Headers + strtolower()
        $return['headers'] = $headers;

        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $items = str_getcsv($row);
            if ( count($items) !== count($headers) ) continue;

            $items[2] = new Carbon($items[2]);  // Third item is UTC datetime
            $items[3] = new Carbon($items[3]);  // Fourth item is UTC datetime

            $items = array_combine($headers, $items);

            $return['rows'][] = $items;
        }

        return $return;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::error($e->getMessage());
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

The parent code which call csv2array() looks like this

```
$csv = $request->getContent();
$csv = trim($csv);
$csvArray = $this->csv2array($csv);

$insertArray = $this->addDeviceIdToArray($csvArray['rows'], $device);  // This is fast 0.2s
```

Comment: Do you also know what part of csvToArray is slow? That would be your next check. Is one specific thing slow, of just the amount of rows to process?

Comment: `$rows = explode(PHP_EOL, $csv);` will make it keep the complete file content, in array form, in memory. Using `fgetcsv`, which reads line by line from a file, might perform better. Looks like you don't have a file here, but get the CSV content posted to your app directly? Then you could perhaps either use `php://input` to access it as a readable stream (depends on what exactly you are sending), or write the data to a temporary file first.

Comment: @CBroe yes it is POST input. So you thing the explode is the problem. I will try to save it to the file and read via fgetcsv.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to convert the date values back to string?

Comment: @CBroe you are alluding at the memory usage while the OP evidently is about CPU. Though the OP failed completely to explain the actual problem: what time the whole parsing takes and why it's a concern. Which makes this question ultimately off topic.

Comment: @YourCommonSense yes, I'm aware. But without further, specific measurements, that is where I would start optimizing here. Although rather unlikely with the numbers here, "huge" memory consumption could also slow things down - if the OS needs to start swapping perhaps. One of the main points to prefer `fgetcsv` would IMHO be that it can handle line breaks in column content, whereas simply exploding at line breaks might invalidate the data.

Comment: @CBroe it's just 15K lines. Few megabytes at max. I don't think that any OS would start swapping here. The problem is elsewhere

Comment: it seems the most time consuming part is new carbon. but still, for me it's just same 0.2s for the whole 15k lines. The problem is elsewhere

Comment: I'd say the carbon statements as well. Each instantiation of carbon on 15k rows is likely to be costly. I know it was for me working with 100k rows.

Comment: Ok so another adept to fix is new Carbon(). 
Thanks for all answers. Although I would like to know who downovoted everything what he see.

Comment: Why not use any CSV parsing library, along with a proper profiler that helps you spot the bottleneck? Also, is this problem directly related to Laravel itself? I don't see any calls to Laravel specific functions

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your current setup load everything in one go. You have too many rows for that to be an effective route. You have the 'easy fast' solution, those have limitations.

IMO the most likely issue is the amount of data. You load 15000 lines into `$csv` and then copy that into a huge array. PHP isnt really that good with info like that.

My suggestion is to use `fgetcsv`:

```php
file_put_contents("test.csv", $request->getContent()); // write to file
protected function csvToArray(){
    $handle = fopen("test.csv", "r");
    $i = 0;
    while (($items = fgetcsv($handle, null, ",")) !== false) {
        $i++;
        if($i === 1){
            $headers = $items;
            continue;
        }

        $items[2] = new Carbon($items[2]);  // Third item is UTC datetime
        $items[3] = new Carbon($items[3]);  // Fourth item is UTC datetime

        $items = array_combine($headers, $items);
        $return['rows'][] = $items;
    }

    return $return;
}

file_put_contents("test.csv", $request->getContent()); // write to file

$csvArray = $this->csvToArray();
```

That way you can stream from a file which is a lot less memory intensive and doesnt scal with filesize.
*(Please note that this is demo code, there is room for improvement)*

Comment: Guesswork and conjectures are not good answers for Stack Overflow. Your suggestion won't improve the overall performance of this code.

Comment: Why you thing the fgetcsv() do not improve the performance?